# Problem during code generating after using JHipster JDL-Studio

Tags: parsing, terminal, jhipster, fedora, jdl

Here is an error I get. Please help. I do not have any idea what to do at the moment. Thank you

[...]$ jhipster jdl ~/Pobrane/awex.jdl

INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally

INFO! Executing import-jdl /home/UltimateSystems/Pobrane/awex.jdl

INFO! The JDL is being parsed.

Error: Database type is required to validate entities.

Error while parsing applications and entities from the JDL Error: Database type is required to validate entities.

Error: Database type is required to validate entities.

```
at checkForEntityErrors (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/jdl/validators/jdl-without-application-validator.js:82:13)

at Object.checkForErrors (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/jdl/validators/jdl-without-application-validator.js:69:7)

at checkForErrors (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/jdl/jdl-importer.js:202:13)

at Object.import (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/jdl/jdl-importer.js:115:7)

at JDLProcessor.importJDL (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/import-jdl.js:210:43)

at JDLProcessor.importJDL (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/import-jdl.js:370:34)

at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/import-jdl.js:512:17)

at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/jdl.js:61:49

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

Error during import-jdl: Error: Database type is required to validate entities.

Error: Database type is required to validate entities.

```
at checkForEntityErrors (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/jdl/validators/jdl-without-application-validator.js:82:13)

at Object.checkForErrors (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/jdl/validators/jdl-without-application-validator.js:69:7)

at checkForErrors (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/jdl/jdl-importer.js:202:13)

at Object.import (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/jdl/jdl-importer.js:115:7)

at JDLProcessor.importJDL (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/import-jdl.js:210:43)

at JDLProcessor.importJDL (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/import-jdl.js:370:34)

at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/import-jdl.js:512:17)

at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/jdl.js:61:49

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

ERROR! Error during import-jdl: Database type is required to validate entities.

Error: Error during import-jdl: Database type is required to validate entities.

```
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/import-jdl.js:527:27)

at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/jdl.js:61:49

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

Comment: The error seems clear, you did not select a database. Please post your JDL

Comment: Oh, ye, I tried to execute command from the wrong folder - it was a problem, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just to give this question an answer.

As @user15545005 said in his comment, `jhipster jdl` command was executed from the wrong directory.

So if you are having this problem, make sure you are running `jhipster jdl` command from the **root directory** of your project.